# Third-party advertisement and Imgur images not loading

Tags: support, status-norepro, advertising, images

For some reason, images from Imgur as well as in third-party advertisements (not directly related to Stack Exchange) are not loading.  I only get alternate text in its place.  I have no problems with any other sites and images that are part of the Stack Exchange interface as well as ads related to SE are loading normally.  Bypassing and clearing the cache in the browser does not help, and it is noticeable on all SE sites Is there a problem?

Comment: This happens to me because Imgur is blocked from our network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see images from imgur just fine:  http://meta.superuser.com/ads/display/2164

It could be a temporary issue from your location.

Comment: See this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wrJOT.png

Comment: OK, this looks like a DNS server problem.  [Down or Not](http://www.downornot.com/i.stack.imgur) says that it is up, but my browser says "server not found" on trying to access [i.stack.imgur.com](http://i.stack.imgur.com).

Comment: The images are now loading normally.  i.stack.imgur.com redirects to stack.imgur.com, an information page on Stack Exchange's Imgur account.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me as well when I'm at a client's premises.  I don't care too much about the ads but not being able to upload to imgur is quite a pain in the neck.  This LAN is actually [severely crippled](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3778/getting-self-signed-ssl-certificates-for-all-https-connections-made-from-some-pre).

Another possibility is that you might be running [add block plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/).  But this is easy to diagnose since you can temporarily disable this FF/Chrome extension or may be use IE.

Comment: AdBlockPlus is not installed.