# Images manually uploaded to Imgur are not displaying?

Tags: support, images, imgur

I noticed that on at least [one of my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796103/jquery-in-chrome-console-8-0-552-237/4976178#4976178), the recent imgur problem reared its 404 heads:

[image]

The broken url is https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c4aL.png.

I already took a look at:

- [Is imgur losing images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75105/is-imgur-losing-images)
- [Third-party advertisement and Imgur images not loading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93721/third-party-advertisement-and-imgur-images-not-loading)
- [My Stack Overflow imgur images are disappearing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94989/my-stack-overflow-imgur-images-are-disappearing)

After reading the last question above, played around with different subdomains:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c4aL.png (same as above, clearly does not worK)
- [http://stack.imgur.com/9c4aL.png](https://stack.imgur.com/9c4aL.png) (redirects to the same broken URL)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l6mm.png (**aha!** It works)
- [http://stack.i.imgur.com/9c4aL.png](https://stack.i.imgur.com/9c4aL.png) (redirects to the above, non-broken URL)

What's up? Do I need to go and manually check all of my answers for broken image links?

Comment: Did you upload to imgur yourself, or did you upload via the SE editor controls?

Comment: I just commented on Jeff's answer - it appears that this was one of the few times that I used my own imgur account.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For all posts made on or after [August 17 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), any image urls in the form of `i.imgur.com` were changed to `i.stack.imgur.com` network-wide.

This means, if …

- your post was made on or after **August 17 2010**
- **you *MANUALLY* uploaded something to imgur, that is, outside of clicking the 'add image' button in our editor**
- your image URL will be broken and you'll have to manually edit it back to the old `i.imgur.com` form

Sorry, we assumed that 99% of users would be using the default image upload support provided by the editor, so those users who deviated will be affected.

Comment: ...dammit, that's one of the [seven images I used my own account for](http://mattjball.imgur.com/stack_overflow). Thanks, Jeff!

Comment: man I need to go through my posts done having imgur urls to check for broken links now :\

Comment: @JeffAtwood - I'm not sure the note about images disappearing after 6 months is really clear.  Would it be correct to say that users who used the "add image" button do not have to worry about this sort of expiration?

Comment: From imgur FAQ: **How long do you keep the images?** _As long as images are getting at least 1 view every 6 months, they will stick around forever. After that, your image may be removed to create more space for newer images._ So in practice it's a problem only for users who do not constantly view their all images at least once a few months (which is a good practice for many reasons). :-)

Comment: @prz we've seen images get removed by imgur that should have had views. I would not trust that guidance as 100% accurate.

Comment: @Jeff: I see. This rule was most likely more restrictive in the past, so I hope you've just seen examples of images that were uploaded and have vanished before rules were changed (dunno when it was done exactly). Anyway, it's surely safer to use SX imgur. Thus I'll have to update my TeX.SX posts within 6 months, just in case...

Comment: @prz, but now some of those images will not get any view at all, simply as their true URL has been changed into a `i.stack.imgur.com` URL, which does not apply to non-SE images.

Comment: I'm quite curious why this was done? If you're regretting this: a year ago, [sth used a datadump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with/99241#99241) to download all images for SO. I guess that could be repeated using a pre-June 2011 dump, if the images are important.

Comment: @arjan the ambiguity was extremely painful, and the broken images are more obviously wrong than an image which may randomly disappear at any time because it was not uploaded through an imgur pro account.

Comment: @Jeff, it seems something went bad with the URL change. I'm sure I've used the SE upload [when changing a post in January](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1348248/revisions). Meanwhile, the URLs were updated in the Markdown. However, 1) I still see the old URLs in [the cooked HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273428/how-do-i-stop-the-jquery-ui-slider-from-sliding-beyond-the-gutter/1348248#1348248) and 2) **one** of the two old image URLs no longer shows the image: http://i.imgur.com/HAjPB.png When I add `stack` all is fine, and I assume making a dummy edit would fix the cooked HTML.

Comment: Fun fact: the official [i.imgur.com/not-here.png](http://i.imgur.com/not-here.png) shows a different 404 image than SE [i.stack.imgur.com/not-here.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/not-here.png) The first even [serves a GIF](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2Fnot-here.png&http=1.1&gzip=yes&type=GET&uak=0) rather than a PNG.

Comment: @Sathya, beware: maybe the new URLs are only used after making some edit! (See my comments above but please do not edit *my* post to ensure the team can have a look if needed.)

Comment: The cooked HTML [for another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75105/is-imgur-losing-images) that has not been edited since January, *does* include the new `stack` in the image URLs. Odd?

Comment: (Same for http://i.imgur.com/ObK9i.png versus http://i.stack.imgur.com/ObK9i.png)

Comment: (Same for http://i.imgur.com/Dd5Ow.png versus http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd5Ow.png, which I used [in a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83548/revealing-voting-patterns-new-trend#comment-204570))

Comment: @arjan as I said above, we rewrote history, Terminator 2 style. We went back in time and made it as if everyone used i.stack even if they didn't.

Comment: @Jeff, I thought you meant: as if everybody used *the SE-provided upload*. Just to be sure: all my Imgur images were uploaded using the image button in the toolbar, to your Pro account. (I use that button for comments too; I just copy the result into a comment.) And the post I refer to in my first July 23rd comment has two images, only one of which now fails for the old URL? That aside: the cooked HTML might not have been changed in all occasions. (It's not a problem for me; just FYI.)

Comment: So, @Jeff, what I see does not match [your statement](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/the-image-you-are-requesting-does-not-exist-or-is-no-longer-available/1411#1411) *"We have a network level "pro" account, so images shouldn't be disappearing, and they should be in both places actually."* (That is: if you mean they shouldn't be disappearing from either place.)

Comment: @arjan it's possible, though incorrect, for them to disappear from `i.imgur.com`. We don't care so much about that any more, as all the images *should* (I mean, that were properly uploaded by users via our upload support in the first place..) have been properly migrated to `i.stack.imgur.com` which we *do* care about.

Comment: In case it ever matters: the cooked HTML for [another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55162/if-many-comments-are-deleted-by-flagging-then-show-them-as-deleted-for-some-time) was [not rebuilt either](http://i.stack.imgur.com/svyk3.png), after the Markdown source was automagically changed earlier. A dummy edit fixed that. Slightly confusing: the preview shows the image just fine, as that creates the cooked HTML on the fly.

Comment: @Jeff, Gareth is doing a lot of fixing [for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z9ud.png) and [others](http://superuser.com/users/73637/gareth?tab=activity#page_1-filter_revisions) as more and more images no longer show. So I guess [More and more images go missing. Can the cooked HTML be rebuilt?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104856/more-and-more-images-go-missing-can-the-cooked-html-be-rebuilt) is needed more and more...

Comment: What date did you do this site-wide rename exactly?