# Is it possible to have some freehand feature with posts?

Tags: discussion

Before I ask, I've read this question:

[A picture is worth a thousand words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122091/a-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-words)

With a question I just answered with a picture

[C# Loop Through An Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224785/c-sharp-loop-through-an-array/16225389#16225389)

Since I cannot find a better way to point the code errors at exact places, I can only use a picture.

I'm wondering, if there was and I'm not aware or, is it possible to have some freehand feature with posts?

Comment: Use MSPaint! Or your platforms equivalent.

Comment: @Linuxios: Yep, I did something like that, but seems the question on meta which I mentioned, does not encouraged that.

Comment: What the question on meta which you mentioned says is that some explanatory text must be included with posts, although the rules seem to be relaxed here (see below).  Pictures are not searchable via Google, and blind people cannot see them, so unless you include alt text, they're useless from an accessibility standpoint.

Comment: Maybe you would want to try this - [StackExchange™ SuperCollider Freehand Circle™ Editor - Now supported on EVERY StackExchange site!](http://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor-now-supported-on-every-s)

Comment: @Aditya: I've just installed the user script, but `There was an error retrieving the new image URL.` on everytime I tried to save.

Comment: @KenKin: I won't be able to help much. It would be better if you post it on its Stack Apps page. (If you don't know, Stack Apps is a part of Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Freehand circles can be drawn with MSPaint]

Comment: Zero-word answer, because a picture is worth a thousand words. Well-done.