# Why can some people not see images that I upload?

Tags: support, imgur

I have recently tried illustrating answers on stackoverflow with images created by:

1. Drawing image in Inkscape
2. Saving image in Cairo .png format
3. Uploading it from my computer to an answer via the ctrl-G option.

However, both times I tried this (e.g. at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359293/push-flow-relabel-algorithm/11359470#11359470) ) I have received comments that people have been unable to view the diagram.

I'll also attempt to add the same diagram here:
[image]

However, I always seem to be able to view the images myself (even if I use different browsers (firefox/chrome), and different computers, and even if I am not logged in as myself).

My question is why are some people unable to view these images? (and is there a different approach to creating diagrams that I should use instead?)

Comment: Yes indeed, many work places and ISP's are blocking imgur domain. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109975/hosting-options-for-people-that-have-imgur-blocked-by-isp) post.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to stick to text diagrams in future then.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz: No, not if an image is better.