# i.stack.imgur.com images being blocked

Tags: support, images

This might wind up be closed as too localized but I figured I would post asking for help.

This morning when I got into work I noticed that images on Stack Overflow questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685651/sum-over-sum-in-sql-server)) are being blocked if they are hosted on [i.stack.imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com).

If I browse directly to the URL of the image I get the lovely **Blocked Website** message that our company uses for inappropriate and restricted websites.

Our organization uses [Bluecoat](http://www.bluecoat.com/) to determine the site's allowed or not allowed based on the categorization of the site.  [i.stack.imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com) is classified as *Online Storage* thus is restricted for usage. But I can browse to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) with no restrictions.

Any chance you can fixed this by getting [i.stack.imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com) reclassified?

Comment: stack.imgur is also blocked where I work, however it's determined by our IT department. Domain blocking software is usually configurable to each company since not everywhere is going to want to block the same sites. I suggest you enquire with your IT dept.

Comment: @Ian they will only unblock websites that have legitimate business reason for usage.  stack.imgur.com will not fall into category of  legitimate business need. I think stack.imgur.com just got moved into the *Online Storage* category since I had no issues last week.

Comment: @bluefeet Is i.imgur.com blocked? Here's [a random example pulled from their front page](http://i.imgur.com/D6sji.gif) to test. If you're a programmer Stack Overflow *must* be considered a legitimate business resource, and `stack.imgur` is part of that.

Comment: @JeremyBanks no that is not blocked, just stack.imgur is blocked

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com is ["currently categorized as Computers/Internet and Online Storage"](http://sitereview.bluecoat.com/sitereview.jsp). You may be able to convince your IT department to whitelist it based on its usage in Stack Overflow; my IT department has apparently done so.

Comment: @mmyers I will submit a request to our IT department but it can take up to 3 months for it to be re-categorized.

Comment: I have the same issue. Closed why? unlikely to help any future visitors? (Wrong). Relevant to small geographic area (wrong) specific moment in time (wrong) extraordinary blah blah blah (wrong).

Comment: In my opinion, this is not too localized, as in many locations imgur and subdomains are blocked  for questionable content/media/bandwidth/generic excuse. Please reopen for consideration.

Comment: I have the same issue.   I'm working on convincing my IT security folks to whitelist i.stack.imgur.com but am not very hopeful...

Comment: Here's the answer I got:  "It’s a sharing site and (my company name) proprietary information can be uploaded there – therefore its blocked on those grounds. "  sigh

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109975/201151)

Answer (score 7):

Here's my [Tampermonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tampermonkey) script that replaces [Imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur) links with a proxy search engine links. It works fine for me, better than using a proxy.

Proxy search engine: [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com)

Tampermonkey: [Download](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           imgur to duckduckgo
// @description    Replaces all imgur links on reddit with duckduckgo links
// @include        https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include        https://stackexchange.com/*
// @include        https://stackoverflow.com/*

// ==/UserScript==

changeImages();
changeAnchors();


function changeImages()
{
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
        var p = /imgur\.com/;
        var src = images[i].src;
        var res = p.exec(src);

        if (res!=null) {
            images[i].src = 'https://duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=' + src;
        }
    }
}

function changeAnchors()
{
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        var p = /imgur\.com/;
        var href = a[i].href;
        var res = p.exec(href);

        if (res!=null) {
            a[i].href = 'https://duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=' + href;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) code script to replace imgur images with a web archived image using jQuery.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stackoverflow Images
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take replace imgur images with a web archived image.
// @author       You
// @match        *stackoverflow.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=stackoverflow.com
// @grant        none
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    $("img").each(function(ignore, e) {
        var $e = $(e);
        if ($e.attr("src").startsWith("http://i.stack.imgur")) {
            $e.attr("src", "http://web.archive.org/web/" + $e.attr("src"));
        }
    });

})();
```