# How do I access a banned Imgur site?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur

Maybe you know, imgur.com is banned in Turkey. So we can't see images on asked questions and can not upload any image to questions. Is there an alternative to imgur.com for downloading/uploading images?

Or can you suggest anything to get rid of this?

Comment: Maybe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157459/i-stack-imgur-com-images-being-blocked might help?

Comment: Does the Wayback Machine work (for viewing the images)? E.g. this ugly fellow: https://web.archive.org/web/20190906074048/https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haz6W.jpg

Comment: Is YouTube banned as well?

Comment: "Or can you suggest anything to get rid of this?" Elect an official that will lift that ban.

Comment: No @PeterMortensen, YouTube is not banned, for now.

Comment: I hope some day we will elect somebody else ,@nvoigt, but I don't know when and how.

Comment: For information, here in China: no imgur, no wayback machine, no jquery hosted on Google, no login with Facebook, no login with Twitter, no YouTube, no Wikipedia, no DuckDuckGo, no popular VPN, no <insert anything popular in America>... it's a miracle that we still have access to Stack Exchange.

Comment: Be careful @Cœur. If they realize that you still access to StackExchange, they can ban here as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I added these lines to hosts file and now some images (mostly i.stack.imgur.com urls) are visible. Actually, I viewed dozens of questions and can see images without any problem. It shouldn't be that simple.

```
107.21.3.138 apidocs.imgur.com
151.101.36.193 api.imgur.com
104.16.53.111 help.imgur.com
151.101.36.193 blog.imgur.com
52.23.39.2 browserevents.imgur.com
151.101.36.193 p.imgur.com
151.101.36.193 s.imgur.com
151.101.36.193 store.imgur.com
151.101.36.193 i.imgur.com
151.101.36.193 i.stack.imgur.com
151.101.60.193 imgur.com
151.101.36.193 m.imgur.com
```

Comment: Lol, dodging DNS lookups works:)

Comment: Surprisingly, yes, they do :)