# Self hosting of integrated thumbnails for photos on SE sites

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader, imgur

I think it'd be a good idea to start including integrated low res thumbnails on images in questions, as at least for the case of my school, Imgur is blocked and half of the sites are just broken image icons all over the place.

I think just having a site specific thumbnail path (ex. stackoverflow.com/thumb), a user content subdomain (ex. usercontent.stackoverflow.com), or a combination of the two. (maybe add compatibility for file attachment for stuff like dump diagnosis and the like?)

Specifically, it could either kick in when the image fails to load from Imgur, or just allowing the user to click on the image for a high res preview from Imgur.

What are everyone's thoughts on this?

Comment: That would be total waste of time/resources to double host all images. If SE decides to self host, they'll host the full image. As far as I can tell, storage isn't the issue.

Comment: @Garret for the record, while I downvoted too because I disagree with the idea, please don't take it personal. I'm sorry you can't see images, it's bad experience, but what you suggest is simply not a good idea, overall.

Comment: If it were not for this being a Feature Request and the other being Support I'd suggest that [this is a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64404/282094); so I'll leave it up to you Garrett. --- See also [this solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83596/282094) there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How much does your school want to pay to cater for the development time, site-reliability and maybe other on-going operational costs for moving images under an SE domain?

It is worth noting that the images are uploaded to a specific domain for Stack Exchange, namely, i.stack.imgur.com. Your school need to whitelist that domain and ignore the fact that it is under the imgur.com domain. This is therefor a network configuration issue on your end.

Maybe the answer on [i.stack.imgur.com images being blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157459/i-stack-imgur-com-images-being-blocked) can help you deal with over-zealous network administrators.

It seems unlikely that a large portion of the userbase/visitors of the sites will benefit from implementing your feature request. Therefor my thought on it is to leave it to end-users to cater for their own network requirements as explained in [What else do I need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100)